# Why answers don't have a "locked" attribute?

Tags: support, status-completed, answers, locked-posts

When looking at an answer, I can see that there is no `locked_date` attribute, like [there is for questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions). IIRC, answers can be locked by moderators.

Also, if a post is unlocked, is that field blanked?

Comment: Do you have any sample locked answer, but not deleted one?

Comment: Ya, an example would help.

Comment: Sure, [here you go](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518). Although it is unlocked now, it used to be locked not so long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locked_date` has been placed on both questions and answers now.